# getdata join function in model not properly working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I tried to make a model function so I can echo user detail information on a page with a join fuction in my model. But than when I try to echo a row it gets echoed 7 times. So it will be echoed whenever user's email matched with the products. but I only want the name to echo once..

This is my getdata function in my model:

```
public function getdata()
    {
        $this->db->select('users.user_id,users.email,users.voornaam,products.product_id,products.category_id,products.product_naam');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->join('products','products.user_id = users.user_id');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows()>0)
        {
           return $query->result_array();
        }
```

And this is an example as how I'm trying to echo name(voornaam) in my view :

```
<div class="aangeboden_door">   Aangeboden door:    <?php 
          foreach($userdetail_list as $row): ?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url() . 'User/userdetails/'.$row['user_id']?>">
           <?php echo $row['voornaam'];?>

        </a>
```

controller function:

```
public function details($product_id)
  {
    //load the Product_model
    $this->load->model('Product_model');
    //call function getdata in de Product_model
    $data['userdetail_list'] = $this->Product_model->getdata();

    //get product details
    $data['product'] = $this->Product_model->get_product_details($product_id);

    //laad view
    $data['main_content'] = 'details';
    $this->load->view('details',$data); 
  }
```

TABLE STRUCTURE:

```
Table 1 : products:

product_id
product_naam
product_beschrijving
user_id
ophaal_plaats
product_foto
product_foto_thumb
date_created
date_updated
category_id

table 2 : users:

user_id
email
voornaam
achternaam
beschrijving
profiel_foto
```

anyone got a solution for my getdata function to only echo the user name (voornaam) once?

Comment: Please post your table structure data.

Comment: OK check my updated question, that is what you mean with table structure right?

Comment: Hello do you have any solution do this sir? or other code that works to get userdetails of a product owner?

Comment: You can try left join in your query. `$this->db->join('products','products.user_id = users.user_id','left');`

Comment: When I try left. it shows all the usernames from the database table 'users' you have any other solution?